# Magento tab change/redirect

Tags: magento, redirect, tabs

I have a page with two tabs, a search-tab and a tab with a grid of the database. After the user edits one of the items in the grid, I'd like to keep them on the grid tab, rather than the form tab which is first in order.

Is there a way to change the active tab on a page via code?

This is the code for the tabs:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->addTab('search_string', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Find a string'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Find a string'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("advancedtranslate/adminhtml_advancedtranslate")->toHtml(),
        'active'    => true
    ));

    $this->addTab('list_untranslated', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Untranslated strings'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Untranslated strings'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("advancedtranslate/adminhtml_grid")->toHtml(),
        'active'    => false
    ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

And this is the saveAction in my controller that handles the redirect:

```
public function saveAction(){
    //write data away to core_translate table
    $resource   = Mage::getResourceModel('core/translate_string');

    $request              = $this->getRequest();
    $translate_id         = $request->getParam('id');
    $original             = $request->getParam('original_translation');
    $custom               = $request->getParam('string');
    $locale               = $request->getParam('locale');
    $storeId              = $request->getParam('storeid');
    $storeViewSpecific    = $request->getParam('storeview_specific');

    if($storeId != 0 && $storeViewSpecific != 1){
        $storeId = 0;
    }

    $resource->saveTranslate($original, $custom, $locale, $storeId);

    //delete record from phpro table
    $advancedTranslateRecord = Mage::getModel('advancedtranslate/advancedtranslate');

    $advancedTranslateRecord->setId($translate_id)
                            ->delete();

    //clear the cache
    Mage::app()->getCache()->clean();

    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')
                                           ->__('Translation was saved.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: Sure thing that there is a way to do this. Unfortunately you have not posted your code that gives you the trouble so no one can really help or suggest you anything here and questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do so by changing the 'active' => true / false attribute in your _beforeToHtml()
... simply pass a parameter or set a session value in your saveAction()... so when the page gets redirected you check in your beforeToHtml() if the parameter is set you change the order of 'active' => $somevariable.

So basically do,

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
        $active = true;
        if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData('ActiveTab')) {
            $active = false;
        }
    $this->addTab('search_string', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Find a string'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Find a string'),
    'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("advancedtranslate/adminhtml_advancedtranslate")->toHtml(),
    'active'    => $active
    ));

    $this->addTab('list_untranslated', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Untranslated strings'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Untranslated strings'),
    'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("advancedtranslate/adminhtml_grid")->toHtml(),
    'active'    => !$active
    ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Why not just

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/', array('active_tab' => 'list_untranslated'));
```