# Magento Admin Customer Edit Tabs

Tags: magento

I have been successful developing a Customer Notes Tab in Magento Admin Customer Edit, with everything functioning correctly. However whan a CSR saves a customer Note in the tab magento will update the table and return to the default top tab of "Customer View" I would like the action on the customer notes section on save to return to the customer notes tab.
this is my controller

```
    <?php class Mycompany_Customernotes_CustomernotesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
            public function saveAction()
            {
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

                $returnnotes[] =  $this->getRequest()->getPost();           
                        foreach ($returnnotes as $returnnote) {
                            $notes = $returnnote['customer_notes'];
                            $customer_id = $returnnote['customer_id'];
                            $user_id = $returnnote['userId'];
                            $username = $returnnote['username'];
                            $timestamp = $returnnote['timestamp'];

                $write->query("INSERT into Blah Blah Blah

                }
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
    }
```

This is Magento EE 1.12

Thanks in advance for any insite.

UPDATE showing config.xml

```
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <customernotes>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mycompany_Customernotes</module>
                <frontName>customernotes</frontName>
            </args>
        </customernotes>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $this->_redirect('*/*/', array('active_tab' => 'list_untranslated'));
```

See [Magento tab change/redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671358/magento-tab-change-redirect)

Comment: Being the page URL is /customer/edit/id/185208/ the redirect to active tab returns a 404.

Comment: Does your admin url require a form key? eg. /customer/edit/id/185208/ /key/8e7af61..199e064b3/

Comment: Also take a look at my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501360/magento-custom-admin-module-404-not-found ... which way did you define you admin route in your config.xml ... Are you doing `<Company_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">`

Comment: @ RS ~ I copied the config up one the original post. And as far as the Form Key. i am using a form key on the notes form.

Comment: The reason it is not working is because of the way you define your config.xm by not using <Company_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">. If take a look at your admin url for your customer section you will notice it site.com/[admin]/customer/edit while your custom module is site.com/mymodule/edit (without [admin])

Answer (score 0):

The class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs appears to deal with setting the active tab in the following function.

```
protected function _updateActiveTab()
{
    $tabId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('tab');
    if( $tabId ) {
        $tabId = preg_replace("#{$this->getId()}_#", '', $tabId);
        if($tabId) {
            $this->setActiveTab($tabId);
        }
    }
}
```

Try setting the "tab" parameter before you redirect and see what happens. For an example id the address tab is "customer_info_tabs_addresses"